# Vuetify 3 change event in v-select

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3

I am testing Vuetify 3 (npm:@vuetify/nightly@next) v-select and try to get change event. However, my handler function is not called. This is my code:

**TS:**

```
export default defineComponent({

  setup() {

    function onLanguageChange(a: any) {
      console.log(a);
    }
    const items = ['Русский', 'English'];

    return {onLanguageChange, items}
  }
});
```

**Vue**

```
 <v-select
    prepend-icon="mdi-web"
    :items="items"
    label="Lang"
    @change="onLanguageChange"
  ></v-select>
```

And this is what I get in console when I focus select and change its value.

[image]

Could anyone say, if this is a bug or something is wrong with my code (and how to fix it)?

Comment: its not red/error so it should be fine. Vuetify 3 is still in [alpha](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation) phase, so there may be issues

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`v-select`'s [event list](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select#events) does not include the `change` event. It only has one event: `update:modelValue`.

Use the `update:modelValue` event instead:

```html
<v-select @update:modelValue="onLanguageChange">
```

[demo 1](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/VwrWPPy?editors=1011)

Or use a `v-model` with a watcher:

```html
<v-select v-model="lang">...</v-select>
```

```js
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const lang = ref()
    watch(lang, (newValue) => console.log('new lang', newValue))
    return { lang }
  }
}
```

[demo 2](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/NWwgdvV?editors=1011)

Comment: Thanks, I was about to get crazy right here. Thought it was a lack of documentation in the v-select's page, so I was blindly trying to use the @change event (lol).